How to free the input argument of a class in its constructor?
I'd like to build a GUI for an OLED screen application. I've built one class per menu frame. In each class I need to manage screen updating and key events in a loop. When a certain key is pressed I create an instance of the next class corresponding to the next menu frame. But the instance of the current menu frame still exists.
Then how to free the instance of the calling class when creating the object of the next menu frame?
I tried do something like:
class Menu1():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        if a == 1:      
            menu = Menu2(self)
     
    def doIexist(self):
        print("yes")

class Menu2(): 
    def __init__(self, caller):
        del caller
        print("hello")

toto = Menu1(1)
toto.doIexist()

But it returns
hello
yes


doIexist prints "yes", so what else did you expect toto.doIexist() to do?

Short answer, if I understand your question correctly: you can't and you shouldn't need to.

Your logic makes no sense. You want to create Menu2 in Menu1, but then delete Menu1. What do you think is going to happen to Menu2 when you delete Menu1? If you are using an OLED, I am going to assume you are on a system with limited resources. The best thing to do would likely be to have some state file, and simply reset the entire board loading the current state from the file. This way you know that only the necessary things are in memory.

sorry, I don't understand mkrieger comments. @oystershucker, the code works well. This is a demo. In reality the class menu2 is instanciated under conditions, typically if the correct key is triggered. Menu frames behave well with IR remote interactions in my app, but I'm wondering about memory usage. In the demo, the problem is the object called toto still exists after the object menu has been created.

I know implementing a machine state is a solution. But the approach with classes works too.

del just removes a reference, it doesn't do anything to the object it refers to. The garbage collector will remove the object when there are no more references to it.

Thks Barmar. Your answer helped me a lot.

As long as toto refers to the Menu1 object, there is still a reference to Menu1 so it won't be freed.

Python is a language with no manual memory management, it exposes no way to "free" an object. It's main garbage collection strategy is reference counting. del doesn't delete objects, it removes names from namespaces, in this case, del caller is removing the name caller from the function local namespace in __init__ (which would happen anyway when the function terminates)

From what I read in the comments, I just need to remove
del caller

and let python manage the memory with the garbage collector
